# What does 'variable: value' mean in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vyper

I came across the following syntax in some Python3 code [I found online](http://viper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vyper-by-example.html):

*Note: this is actually from Vyper, a subset of Python3 used for programming on Ethereum. The developers of Vyper claim that all Vyper code is valid Python3 syntax (although the converse is not true)*

```
myvariable: somefunction(someglobalvariable)
```

I haven't been able to uncover the specific documentation from Python3 explaining the meaning of this syntax.

What does this do?

Comment: Somewhat unclear what are you asking about

Comment: Assignment using the colon operator is not valid Python(2 or 3) syntax outside of a dictionary.

Comment: @vaultah ah, no, I was just misunderstanding the notation. This isn't assignment it's type hinting

Comment: (that said, I learned something new -- I've only used annotations in function signatures and did not know they were valid elsewhere)

Comment: **@Makoe**, it doesn't  look like a Python3's syntax. It's related to the state variables that **Vyper** understands well. The coders of **Vyper**  have made their own syntax to force  package users to follow their syntax to work with the package so that they could work with the package nicely. You check http://viper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structure-of-a-contract.html#structure-state-variables and read more about defining state variables

Comment: "It doesn't look like Python3's syntax". [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) begs to differ.